# ASP.NET MVC 5 Authentication on Mono

Tags: mono, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm still quite new with ASP.NET MVC and trying to learn it. Currently on Ubuntu Linux with Mono 3.2.8 installed and followed this [instruction](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/G54G220114-Custom-Authentication-and-Authorization-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html) but encountered 2 issues, one is related to the *Html.AntiForgeryToken()*(followed instructions on how to generate and use machineKey) and *System.Web.Security.MembershipPasswordAttribute*(which is still not yet implemented).

Is there an effective way or instructions on how to implement an authentication system for ASP.NET MVC that runs on Mono?

My last resort is to make my own authentication structure with manual redirection.

Comment: There are still some missing pieces in Mono for MVC5 to work, even in the latest Mono 3.10. MVC4 works afaik.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderKöplinger but currently Monodevelop 5 only have MVC5 project template.